# Will it ever rain on the island?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In Animal Crossing: New Leaf, will it ever rain on the Island?  I want to catch a snail on one of the hibiscus bushes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After about a month of Island trips I'm pretty confident it never rains on the island, even when it's raining at your town.

Instead, to catch a snail you'll need to plant a hibiscus bush in your town (they sell starter plants at the island shop sometimes, they cost 5 medals and come in assorted colors) and wait for it to rain, and you'll have a chance to see a snail. They seem somewhat rare but I have caught one using this method.

Comment: Judging by the other 2 answers, I suspect this may be wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it can rain on the island, and when it does, you can find snails:

[image]
[image]

**EDIT:** If you're looking for rain on the island, you might want to check it in the morning.  For the last two weeks, I've visited the island each day in the late afternoon or evening, and haven't seen it rain once during that time.  However, I've seen it rain on three separate morning visits, at just past 8:00AM.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, it CAN rain - it's raining on my island right now - but this is the first time since I've gotten the game, so I'm guessing that it's very rare.

Comment: Mind snapping a screenshot for us?  That would be great to see. You can do so in Animal Crossing by holding the L & R bumpers.

Comment: A screenshot would be perfect.  :)

Answer (score 3):

It's raining on mine right now, and I was really creeped out lol. The music doesn't play, there's just a bird squawking, and the pitter patter of the rain O.o

Comment: Take a screenshot of it. You can do so in Animal Crossing by holding the L & R bumpers (like Hyper Anthony mentioned above)

Answer (score 1):

It does rain on the island. Go there just about after 8:00 A.M. and there's a chance of it raining there. Nothing better than a morning rain. Animal Crossing wikia lies about it being impossible to catch a coelacanth on the island. That's where I caught mine actually. very rare though. :)